# Regex Search Replace for Multiple Files in a Directory using Python

Tags: python, regex

Where am I going wrong ??

```
import os, os.path, re

path = "D:\python-test"
myfiles = os.listdir(path)

REGEXES = [(re.compile(r'dog'), 'cat'),
           (re.compile(r'123'), '789')]
for f in myfiles:

    file_name, file_extension = os.path.splitext(f)

    if file_extension in ('.txt', '.doc', '.odt', '.htm', '.html', '.java'):

        input_file = os.path.join(path, f)

        with open(input_file, "w") as fi:
            for line in fi:
                for search, replace in REGEXES:
                    line = search.sub(replace, line)
                fi.write(line)
```

Somehow its not working. I want to make the replacements in the current file and not a new file.

**Update:** How about creating A_reg.java from A.java. Moving A.java to a separate local folder and then renaming A_reg.java back to A.java . Possible ? If yes, please help me out with the code.

Comment: As soon as the file is opened in `'w'` mode, it is truncated.
use `r+` or `a+` modes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the inputs from Fge. I could make it work by using

```
from shutil import move

move(output_file, input_file)
```

Thus the **working code** will be

```
import os, os.path, re
from shutil import move

path = "D:\python-test"
myfiles = os.listdir(path)

REGEXES = [(re.compile(r'dog'), 'cat'),
           (re.compile(r'123'), '789')]
for f in myfiles:

file_name, file_extension = os.path.splitext(f)
generated_output_file = file_name + "_regex" + file_extension

if file_extension in ('.txt', '.doc', '.odt', '.htm', '.html', '.java'):

    input_file = os.path.join(path, f)
    output_file = os.path.join(path, generated_output_file)

    with open(input_file, "r") as fi, open(output_file, "w") as fo:
        for line in fi:
            for search, replace in REGEXES:
                line = search.sub(replace, line)
            fo.write(line)

move(output_file, input_file)
```

Answer (score 2):

This is perfectly normal: you overwrite the files themselves. Write in *new* files, then rename.

Also, opening the way you do truncates files:

```
$ cat t.txt 
foo
$ python
>>> f = open("t.txt", "w")
>>> f.close()
>>> exit()
$ cat t.txt
# file is empty!!
$
```

Comment: I want to make the replacements in the current file and not a new file. Please help.

Comment: You cannot do that. No program ever does that. Imagine that you write a line which is _longer_ than the original: what do you think will happen?

Comment: @fge -- You certainly can do that.  Of course, as you point out, to get reasonable results, the replacement field needs to be the same size as what it is replacing.  (And this is significantly harder to accomplish than simply writing a new file and renaming)

Comment: @mgilson sure you can, if you are ready to corrupt your inputs. I am not, however ;)

Comment: Or, depending on available resources, you could slurp the whole thing into memory, truncate, and rewrite.

Comment: @fge -- You could pretty easily corrupt your inputs writing a new file and renaming as well ;-).

Comment: @mgilson I fail to see how... Unless your substitution is garbage.

Comment: @Debajyoti trust me, you _really_ don't want to do that. Say you slurp the file into memory, do the substitution and overwrite the file -- but the write fails! What do you do? Believe me, using another file and renaming is the only safe way to do that.

Comment: @fge You are right. My files are in a SVN repository. How about creating A_reg.java from A.java. Moving A.java to a separate local folder and then renaming A_reg.java back to A.java . Possible ?

Comment: What do you mean by "in a SVN repository"? Are you trying to modify the files in the repository itself or from a checkout of yours?

Comment: @fge from a checkout of mine

Comment: Well, you don't have to move the original file. Just write to the replacement file, ensure that it is written, close it, then rename. Renaming is an atomic operation.

Comment: @fge Thats great can you please help me out with that remaining portion of the code.

Comment: Gack! You're doing this in an SVN repository?! Forget *anything* I said about modifying the file in place!