# Python Regex not Working

Tags: python, regex, replace

```
REGEXES = [(re.compile(r'cat'), 'cat2'),
           (re.compile(r'(if)(.*)(\r?\n)(\s*)(logger.info)(.*)'), '\1\2')]

for search, replace in REGEXES:
                    line = search.sub(replace, line)
```

Why is it not working on...

```
if( List != null ) {
   logger.info( "List is not null" );
   fieldSetContainerList.clear();
}
```

Works fine with Notepad++ regex search replace. 
Usage: Want to remove logger.info statements below all if statements.

Comment: Like @NPE said: it should work using `r'\1\2')]` instead of `'\1\2')]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a raw string:

```
       (re.compile(r'(if)(.*)(\r?\n)(\s*)(logger.info)(.*)'), r'\1\2')]
                                                              ^ here
```

With this fix, your regex works for me. Without it, the `\1` and `\2` are processed when the string literal is parsed, and never make it to the regex engine.

Here is my test code:

```
import re

line = """if( List != null ) {
   logger.info( "List is not null" );
   fieldSetContainerList.clear();
}
"""

REGEXES = [(re.compile(r'cat'), 'cat2'),
           (re.compile(r'(if)(.*)(\r?\n)(\s*)(logger.info)(.*)'), r'\1\2')]

for search, replace in REGEXES:
    line = search.sub(replace, line)
print line
```

When run, this prints

```
if( List != null ) {
   fieldSetContainerList.clear();
}
```

Comment: Not sure why its not working for me. See [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14445401/1278540) for the implementation.